# From Paris to Saint-Malo at night

Tags: france

I will reach Paris-Charles de Gaulle Sunday evening at 7.00 PM. Is it possible to go to Saint-Malo in the same day?

Comment: Do you mean by train or other public transportation? It seems that the last train is at 19H57: https://www.sncf.com/fr/itineraire-reservation/itineraire/liste-resultats?uic1=75056&coordX1=2.35085&coordY1=48.8569&uic2=35288&coordX2=-2.0263&coordY2=48.6482&date=1554310838&when=leave-at&label1=Paris%20(Toutes%20gares)&label2=Saint-Malo%20(Toutes%20gares)&typeDepart=COMMUNE&typeArrivee=COMMUNE&listeCodesMode=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. By car, Saint-Malo is 400km away from Charles de Gaulle airport (it would be a little bit shorter from Orly airport), so it is doable

Comment: There's a train from Gare Montparnasse to Rennes, 21:14–23:10.  But there are no connections from Rennes to Saint-Malo that late, and I have no idea if you'd be able to find a taxi to take you from Rennes to Saint-Malo at that time of the night.

Comment: The taxi ride would be brutally expensive, even from Rennes. There's a surcharge on Sundays.

Answer (score 2):

Getting there by car takes about 4 hours by car but driving that much after a long flight is going to be hard. Jetlag might help or make it even harder.

https://fr.mappy.com/#/3/M2/TItinerary/IFRA%C3%A9roport%20de%20Paris-Charles-de-Gaulle%20-%2095700%20Roissy-en-France|TOSaint-Malo%2035400|MOvoiture|PRcar/N151.12061,6.11309,0.26803,48.8259/Z8/

A taxi would likely not even accept to drive from Rennes to St Malo. As an alternative, there are **buses leaving Paris late at night and arriving at Saint Malo right in time for the breakfast.** Even if the plane land at 7PM, expect some delay to cross the border and retreive your luggage.

See for instance these buses:
https://shop.flixbus.fr/search?departureCity=2015&arrivalCity=4748&route=Paris-Saint-Malo&rideDate=28.04.2019&adult=1&_locale=fr&wt_eid=2155510315279605137&wt_t=1555103199941&affiliate=%28not+set%29%2C

I would consider staying in Paris over the night and ride on a TGV changing at Rennes. The first train leaves slightly before 7am and arrives at about 9h30am. In addition, it's more confortable than the bus.

https://en.oui.sncf/en/results/?wishId=5cb104df55481c0dacb5b2ad&interstitial#!/

Answer (score 1):

There are no trains that will get you from Charles de Gaulle to Saint Malo after 19:00.

A taxi or hire car could do it.